# Filter react-admin query by dates

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am using `react-admin`'s [`useGet...`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#specialized-hooks) query to gather data from my rails backend. The main problem here is the filter property (the last pair of curly braces in the useGetList operation). How can i filter the data by Dates (like get only transactions of the last month etc.)

**This is the current (working) approach:**

```
const { data, loading, error } = useGetList(
    'transactions', 
    { page: 1, perPage: 10000 }, 
    { field: 'id', order: 'ASC' }, 
    {},
)
if (loading) return <p>Loading</p>
if (error) return <p>Error</p>
if (!data) return null
```

The entries in the database all have a `createdAt` and `updatedAt` property.

**My approach would be to create a filter like this:**

```
// constraints could be dates that I can easily set beforehand
{ 
    {'createdAt', desiredLowerTimeConstraint, operation: '<='}, 
    {'createdAt', desiredUpperTimeConstraint, operation: '<='} 
}
```

The `react-admin` [documentation](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/docs) is quite sparce with the filter property, I couldn't find good examples for how these objects are supposed to look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on how your API expects filters to look like.

For instance, in REST APIs served by [JSONServer](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#filter), a `_lte` suffix on a query string parameter name indicates that you want results "Less Than or Equal to" the value:

```
GET /transactions?createdAt_lte=2019-12-05
```

Provided you use the `ra-data-simple-rest`, you can craft this request by passing the parameter in the `filter`:

```
const { data, loading, error } = useGetList(
    'transactions', 
    { page: 1, perPage: 10000 }, 
    { field: 'id', order: 'ASC' }, 
    { createdAt_lte: '2019-12-05' },
)
```

If your API behaves differently, then you may use the same syntax for `useGetList`, and transform the parameter in your `dataProvider` before it's sent to the API.